# Validate PathVariable in custom HandlerMethodArgumentResolver

Tags: spring, validation

I need to validate a PathVariable in a Spring Webapp, and I need to do this in many controllers. I don´t want to blow up the contollers with a manual validation, so I tried to use JSR-303 Validation but realized its not supporten on @PathVariable annotated parameters.

My next approach was to implement a own HandlerMethodArgumentResolver and I tried to add custom validation to it in the following way:

```
@Component public class AppDomainIdArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
```

[...]

```
WebDataBinder binder = binderFactory.createBinder(webRequest, null, "enumId");
        arg = binder.convertIfNecessary(arg, paramType, methodParameter);
        if (methodParameter.hasParameterAnnotation(Valid.class)) {
            validateAppDomainId(arg, binder);
        }
```

[...]

```
private void validateAppDomainId(Object value, WebDataBinder binder) {
    if (MyEnum.getMyEnum((Integer) value) == null) {
        binder.getBindingResult()
            .addError(new ObjectError("enumId", "no.valid.my.enum"));
    }
}
```

When I then try to get the Error in the controller with BindingResult.getErrors() errors is empty. How can I add an error in the HandlerMethodArgumentResolver and access it in the controller? Or am I doing something basically wrong...